# Cannot disable text input based on dropdown list selection

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have an html form with a drop down list :

```
<select id="pjsaupf" name="pjsaupf" onChange="changeState()">
        <option value="nu">Nu se aplica</option>
        <option value="pfa">Persoana Fizica Autorizata PFA</option>
        <option value="pja">Persoana Juridica Autorizata PJA</option>   
</select>
```

-- also tried with onchange instead of onChange. Nothing changed.

And i want that when i select the option with the value "nu" to have the following text form disabled, and when choosing "pfa" or "pja" to be enabled :

```
<input type="text" id="company" name="company" class="form-control" placeholder="Companie" disabled>
```

I tried many javascript codes, I will post the most relevant ones. The problem is that when I select "nu" , the "company" is disabled, and it it okay, when i select "pja", it is enabled, and it is okay, but when i select "pfa" it is disabled but should be enabled here..don't figure out what's wrong..

javascript codes:

```
<script>
function changeState() {
    if(document.getElementById("pjsaupf").value == "nu") {
        document.getElementById("company").disabled=true;
    }else

    if(document.getElementById("pjsaupf").value == "pfa") {
        document.getElementById("company").disabled=false;
    }
    else
    if(document.getElementById("pjsaupf").value == "pja") {
    document.getElementById("company").disabled=false;
    } 
}
</script>
```

and the alternative code :

```
<script>
var select = document.getElementById('pjsaupf');

function changeState() {
    switch (this.value) {
        case '1':
            document.getElementById("company").disabled=true;
            break;
        case '2':
            document.getElementById("company").disabled=false;
            break;
        case '3':
            document.getElementById("company").disabled=false;
            break;
    }
}

select.addEventListener('change', changeState);

</script>
```

**EDIT :** I'm running on localhost

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code, and it seems that everything is working fine. When you select `nu`, `company` is getting disabled. When you select `pfa` or `pja`, the `company` is enabled.

Try running the same code in Incognito mode. I think your javascript is cached by your browser and it is not getting updated with the latest code.

Following is a demo:

```js
function changeState() {
    if(document.getElementById("pjsaupf").value == "nu") {
        document.getElementById("company").disabled=true;
    }else

    if(document.getElementById("pjsaupf").value == "pfa") {
        document.getElementById("company").disabled=false;
    }
    else
    if(document.getElementById("pjsaupf").value == "pja") {
    document.getElementById("company").disabled=false;
    } 
}
```

```html
<select id="pjsaupf" name="pjsaupf" onChange="changeState()">
        <option value="nu">Nu se aplica</option>
        <option value="pfa">Persoana Fizica Autorizata PFA</option>
        <option value="pja">Persoana Juridica Autorizata PJA</option>   
</select>

<input type="text" id="company" name="company" class="form-control" placeholder="Companie" disabled>
```

Comment: I tried also with Microsoft edge..no change in the behaviour of the text input. Sometimes none of them get enabled.. I'm running on localhost, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: @Anais Them? as in plural? your only showing us one

Comment: I checked using localhost as well (on chrome and firefox). It works perfectly fine.

Comment: @ArleighHix i meant that either option i select, the company don't change it's state to enabled. sorry

Comment: @ShubhamAgrawal added 2 captures

Comment: @Anais, Sorry, I didn't understand, what do you mean by '2 captures'. In the meantime, I have changed my chrome agent to "Microsoft Edge" and tested, and it still works fine. Are you sure that you are using the correct files? Please check again.

Comment: @ShubhamAgrawal I edited the question here with 2 screenshots of what appears in my page when i select pfa or pja

Comment: Ok. Just confirming, by disabled do you mean that user is not able to edit the text field? Also, can you add your CSS files for a better understanding?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195001/discussion-between-shubham-agrawal-and-anais).

Comment: Summary (for other users): There was an extra "<script>" tags in javascript files, which was causing javascript to fail. Removing those made everything fine.

Answer (score 1):

It does appear to work as-is however, I would like to suggest a more streamlined approach:

```js
function changeState() {
  // this one Boolean comparison is the value you need
  document.getElementById("company").disabled = (document.getElementById("pjsaupf").value == "nu");
}
```

```html
<select id="pjsaupf" name="pjsaupf" onChange="changeState()">
  <option value="nu">Nu se aplica</option>
  <option value="pfa">Persoana Fizica Autorizata PFA</option>
  <option value="pja">Persoana Juridica Autorizata PJA</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="company" name="company" class="form-control" placeholder="Companie" disabled>
```

Comment: i added 2 captures of my page when i select the options that should change company to enabled in the description of the question

Comment: Yes, but they do not help any. Your first javascript works with the html you have shared. There must be some other script running or css that is keeping it disabled. Did you clear your cache and do a hard reload?

Comment: The capture does show that you do at least have some styles set on the elements that is not in your post.